# Changing kendo chart type fades color when Area chart type is also included

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I want to change the kendo chart type dynamically. I am referring to http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/chart-api/index link. I made a change in this code and added one more chart type "area" along with other three chart types. But I see a weird behavior. After clicking on "Area" chart type option the color of the chart gets faded. Then if I click on any other chart type also, the color looks faded. But if I don't click on Area chart type option then color is intact. This happens for all the color themes. Anyone aware of any reasoning or solution for this behavior.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this issue specifically when changing from the "pie" type to the "area" type. The issue ended up being that my datasource had a two series in it when I was rendering the pie chart, and when I changed to the area chart the pie chart had corrupted the chart config a bit. I modified my code to ensure that the pie chart always has a single series of data, and instead of calling "redraw", I called "refresh" when I changed the chart types.